# Linked list code in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I was watching a video on data structures and algorithms offered [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htzJdKoEmO0)

There firstly code for linked list was written as

```
public class SListNode{
    public Object item;
    public SListNode next;
    public SListNode(Object item,SListNode next){
        this.item=item;
        this.next=next; 
    }
    public SListNode(Object item){
        this(item,null);
    }
    public void insertAfter(Object item){
        next=new SListNode(item,next);  
    }
    public SListNode nth(int position){
        if (position==1){
            return this;
        }
        else if ((position<1)|| next==null){
            return null;
        }
        else{
            return next.nth(position-1);
        }

    }
```

Then the lecturer said that there  are two problems associated with this implementation.

1)if  X and Y refer to the same list and if a new item was inserted to x , y doesn't get updated.I **think** this can be checked by

```
public static void main (String args[]){
        SListNode l1=new SListNode("milk",new SListNode(0,new SListNode(1)));
        SListNode l2=l1;
        l2=new SListNode("soap",l2);
        System.out.println(l1.item+ " "+l1.next.item+ " " +l1.next.next.item);
        System.out.println(l2.item+ " "+l2.next.item+ " " +l2.next.next.item);
```

2)when creating an empty list.

Therefore as a solution separate SListClass that maintains head of list was created.

```
public class SList{
    privte SListNode head;
    private int size;
    public SList(){
        head=null;
        size=0;
    }
    public void insertFront(Object item){
    head=new SListNode(item,head);
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to work with SList class.
How to create a linked list with this class?

How is SListNode and Slist classes are connected and how can the methods of SlistNode be called from SList?
Also how has this new implementation provide a solution to earlier problem of if   X and Y refer to the same list and if a new item was inserted to x , y doesn't get updated.

I am new to programming and Java therefore a clear explanation would be great

Comment: I have only quickly scanned the question but X and Y will only differ (with a linked list) if the **head** element is updated because the other list (the one not updated) will still refer to the "second" element. Storing the head in a separate class bypasses this issue as X and Y both refer to the head-wrapper.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with your interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a classic `LinkedList` implementation. `SListNode` represents a **single node** of the list, while `SList` basically represents the **entire list**. It manages the head of your list (and usually some other attributes such as the list's size, maybe a reference to the list's tail etc.).

What you would usually do is use ONLY the `SList` in your code, which than encapsulates and manages your single `SListNodes`. To do that `SList` needs "dictionary methods" for inserting, deleting, finding etc. objects in your list (which are encapsulated inside your `SListNode` elements managed by your `SList`). That is why I think the `SList`-class you have above is not complete yet.

Your code example

```
SListNode l1=new SListNode("milk",new SListNode(0,new SListNode(1)));
SListNode l2=l1;
l2=new SListNode("soap",l2);
```

does not show what the instructor says. What you do here is create one `SListNode` which references `l1`. Then you create a NEW `SListNode`-Object and point `l2` to it (and then you create a "circular reference" to itself). Of course `l1` and `l2` are no longer referencing the same object!

Comment: SList needs methods means should I need to have the insertAfter(),nth() methods in SListNode in SList and not in SlistNode

Comment: No. Methods in `SList` do not *replace* methods in `SListNode`. Say `SList` has a method `insertAtEnd(Object o)` then you would first find the end of your list (which is a reference to an `SNode`-Object. Then you would call your `SListNode`-method insertAfter() on that very node (e.g. `SListNode tail = //find tail here`; tail.insertAfter(Object o);)

Comment: If I want to create a new linked list with items 34,"a",100 how is this done?Is it done by `SListNode l_0=new SListNode(34,new SListNode("a",new SListNode(100)));`.If so then how is the connection with head in SList is made with this linked list `l_0`

Comment: No. You do not want to use the Nodes in your productive code. What you would do is create a new list (e.g. `SList l = new SList();`) and then add elements to that list (e.g. `SList.insertEnd("milk");` / `SList.insertAfter("apple", "milk");` / `SList.insertFront("milk");`). Your SList needs to implement those *dictionary methods*. SList can then cycle through your entire list (by calling the proper methods of `SListNode`, e.g. next()) and perform the proper actions.

Comment: Please understand the difference between your class `SList` (representing the entire List) and your class `SListNode` (representing the elements your list contains of. Every Node has a **payload** (i.e. data) and a **successor**). *Please do not forget to rate and accept my answer*.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I still need help in understanding `head=new SListNode(item,head);`in insertFront().Since head is of typeSListNodehead also have the fields **item** and **next** right?When a new list l is created by `SList l = new SList();` initially head points to null.Then if I call `SList.insertFront("apple");` a new Node is created whose item is pointing to "apple" and the next field of this new Node points to null as head was pointing to null earlier and then the newly created node is pointed to head.next field.

Comment: Then if I call `SList.insertFront( "milk");` again, then a new Node is created with the item field of this new Node being "milk" and the next field of this Node with "milk" as item refers to what head.next was pointing to.That is this new Node's "next" points to the Node with item "apple" and the newly created Node with item milk is assigned to the head.next field.Is this what happens there?In In `head=new SListNode(item,head);` what is passed on as **head** in parameters SListNode(item,**head**).Is it **head.next?**

Comment: Also though I do not assign a **item** for **head** if I write `System.out.println(l.head.item);` it gets printed out "apple"?How can there be a reference to l.head.item?Isn't item field in head is null?Also why can't Node class be also inserted inside SList class?What's the advantage of having two separate classes

Comment: `head=new SListNode(item,head);` in insertFront creates a new Node with "payload" Object item. It takes the current reference of head and assigns ist as the next member of the list. Finally it sets the new reference head should point to to be this new Node.
You need two seperate classes because they do completely different things: one of them represents the nodes the list consists of, the other represents the entire list itself.